# Could not resolve My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath code in .NET 4.0 and above

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have old .NET 2.0  asp.net web application which has a line of code 
Logger.LogFilePath = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\LogFiles\"

I tried to re-create the same application in .NET 4.5 but I could not able to resolve above line of code.
with what else I could substitute the above line of code or what do I do to resolve the issue.

Comment: Maybe `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\LogFiles\")` if the folder already exists, or `System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "\LogFiles\")`